# Yammer attachement

Tags: javascript, yammer

I'm trying to post a message with an attachment image via my application so I used this code :

```
function yamPost(mytoken) {
        var msg_Body = jQuery("#myBody").val();
        var imgData = new FormData();

        var files = $("#attachement").get(0).files;

        if (files.length > 0) {
            imgData.append("attachement1", files[0]);
        }

        yam.platform.request(
        {
            url: "messages.json",
            method: "POST",
            network: "myNetwork",
            header:{
                authorization: "Bearer " + mytoken,
            },
            data: {
                body: msg_Body,
                attachment1: imgData
            },
            contentType: "multipart/form-data",

            success: function (feedResult) {
                console.log("- Yeaaahhh");
                console.log(feedResult);
                debugger;
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                console.log("- Can't post message with attachement");
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
```

and I got error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

I also tried to use `pending_attachment` but I have faced same problem or http500 internal server error...
could anyone please post an example code of how he do it.

### EDIT

I tried a new approach sending the data :

instead of sending a FormData i used this :

```
function readBinary() {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            yamPost(reader.result, token);
        }

        reader.readAsBinaryString(document.getElementById("attachement").files[0]);
    }
```

and each time i do that i faced this exception :

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"

However if i don't include the attachment (**attachment1: imgData or binaryFileOutput**) the message is posted !

Comment: Do you get any further information from the network monitoring in your browser dev tools? Is the file being sent correctly.

Comment: no, in fact, the request is not even executed and no data is dsended to the yammer network.

Comment: Where is the error message coming from in the code? Does it give you a line number or a point in your code that is raising it?

Comment: once reached this line :
yam.platform.request(
the error is thrown,

i tried another thing :
instead of passing a FormData i passed the result of : readAsBinaryString()
and this time i got the Http 500 and a Cross Domain Exception

Comment: Other requests to Yammer are working correctly? Maybe edit your question to include the details of how you used readAsBinaryString and what the response was?

Comment: so I edited my question, all the other request are executed perfectly I can do Like, post messages, get Users Details, get different type of feed.... I only got a problem when I include attachement !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an answer, 
In fact, using the FormData Object was the correct thing to do but I use it on the worng way, you have to append all the properties that you will send on the same FormData Object just like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24815670/2798565), and here is the magic code:

```
function YamPostImage() {
var myData = new FormData();

myData.append('body', "my app images");
myData.append('attachment1', document.getElementById("attachement").files[0]);

yam.platform.request(
{
    url: "messages.json",
    method: "POST",
    network: "my-network",
    data: myData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (feedResult) {
        console.log("- Yeaaahhh");
        debugger;
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log("- Can't post message with attachement");
        debugger;
    }
});
```

}